# Installable CMS similar to CushyCMS?

Tags: html, content-management-system

I'm looking for a CMS system that works similar to [CushyCMS](http://www.cushycms.com), but that I can install on my own server?

I love the functionality and ease of use CushyCMS provides for simple, small sites where setting up and installing a traditional CMS ([Drupal](http://drupal.org/), [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/), [TYPO3](http://typo3.com/)) are not necessary.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!
Troy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Perch](http://grabaperch.com/) is an *excellent* lightweight CMS.

Comment: Looks like it, but it's not free — any ideas for something similar?

Answer (score 3):

For what you're after I'd reccomend ImpressPages CMS

http://www.impresspages.org/

It doesn't use html tags, but its a very easy "drag and drop" style. with clear toolbars available to the site admin, obviously WYSIWYG editing isn't everyones favourite (it's not mine) but for 5 or so pages, it's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

[Orbis CMS](http://www.novo-ws.com/orbis-cms) is an open source alternative to CMSs like CushyCMS. It's built on the same priciples (simplicity, ease-of-use) and features a stylish interface, but is self-hosted and free.

Answer (score 1):

*"modify html pages simply by adding a class but that I can install on one of my own servers"*

Unify does this very nicely [unify.unitinteractive.com](http://unify.unitinteractive.com/) it costs $24.49 per domain, simply upload the unify folder to your webspace and add class="unify" to the areas in the html you want editable.

Another one ideal for a site of 5 pages is pulsePro http://pulsecms.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to write some of your own code/html it might be worth looking at [django-cms](http://django-cms.org/)

Comment: Thanks CdsBoy... But, again, same problem... I could just install wordpress or drupal, but I really don't want to go to that extent for a simple, 5 page site.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know of any yet, but if you want an alternative online service then check out Surreal CMS.  You can also try out Simple CMS, but it's still very new (released into beta a day or two ago).

Comment: Thanks... I've checked out Surreal and Simple prior and both have the same problem... they're SaaS.  I'm looking for something with identical functionality (where I can modify html pages simply by adding a class) but that I can install on one of my own servers.

Comment: Just curious, but why the need to self-host it?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Zimplit](http://www.zimplit.com/index.html)!

Answer (score 0):

SnippetMaster is pretty cool. It's too bad that it's not open-source and free, but at least it has generous and inexpensive licensing schemes (normal, re-brandable, etc.)

It would be nice if it used class names for the content regions, but it uses HTML comments formatted a special way (like IE conditionals) so it's still valid html.

http://www.snippetmaster.com

Answer (score 0):

I built this one [www.kitgui.com](http://www.kitgui.com) so programmers can be programmers in their own language / framework of choice and use a REST-style interface to pull content and HTML 5 javascript reference to be able to let clients manage the editing experience directly on the website pages themselves. HTML 5 allows for the cross-site security to occur these days so everything just made sense to do this. In my ecommerce business its all about how fast you can setup things to get them out the door and get paid. KitGUI makes it so easy you can't really appreciate it unless you try it out. This is brand new so I have no idea if programmers like it or not except for my own devs who are biased of course. I know clients do for sure so please give me some feedback on it if you have time to investigate as I worked my ass off to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Something which is very similiar to CushyCMS is [Unify CMS](http://unify.unitinteractive.com/).

They have a demo which you can [try before you buy](http://unify.unitinteractive.com/demo.php).

You will see that Unify is very similar to CushyCMS and I quote:

> You do not need to know PHP, nor do you need to write your code
>   specifically for Unify. In order to create editable areas on your
>   site, you only need to add “unify” classes to each element. That’s it.

There is no Database to setup, you just upload the files via FTP (or similar) and start adding in classes where you want to have editable regions. They have repeatable regions as well.

Unify currently costs 24.49 and is backed by a [45 day money back guarantee](http://unify.unitinteractive.com/guarantee.php).

[Support is powered by Desk.com](http://unify.desk.com/)

Take a look at [Unify requirements](http://unify.unitinteractive.com/tutorial-server-settings.php) and you will see you can run this in almost any server on the planet; well, almost any server :)